# How to traverse into inner list in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm writing a procedure which counts the number of zeros in a given list. This list could have another nested list. 
The algorithm that I came up with was very straightforward:

- If the current list is null, return 0
- If the current list is another list, call subprogram to count zeros in this list.
- Else keep traversing the parent list and count zeros if any.

However, I always get the error says,

```
 =: expects type <number> as 2nd argument, given: quote; other arguments were: 0
```

and I have no idea how this could be. Any idea?

My attempt was,

```
(define (helper lst)    
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((= 0 (car lst)) (+ 1 (helper (cdr lst))))
        (else (+ 0 (helper (cdr lst))))))

(define (count-zeroes lst)
  (cond 
    ((null? lst) 0)
    (else 
      (if (list? (car lst)) 
          (+ (helper (car lst)) (count-zeroes (cdr lst)))
          (if (= 0 (car lst)) 
              (+ 1 (count-zeroes (cdr lst)))
              (+ 0 (count-zeroes (cdr lst))))))))

(define ll '(0 1 2 0 '(1 0 0)))

(count-zeroes ll)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a helper method like that, per se.  The count-zeroes method can call itself recursively on the car if the car is a list.

I'd go with something like this instead

```
(define (count-zeroes lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) 0)
    ((list? (car lst)) (+ (count-zeroes (car lst)) (count-zeroes (cdr lst))))
    ((equal? (car lst) 0) (+ 1 (count-zeroes (cdr lst))))
    (else (count-zeroes (cdr lst)))
   )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you tell me where did I got wrong? I'm more concerning about the error than the real solution since I'm practicing with list.

Comment: I think the problem is that your list is defined as '(0 1 2 0 '(1 0 0)), when all you need is '(0 1 2 0 (1 0 0)).  In general you usually don't need more than one quote for the list.

Comment: Ah, I think it may be your use of = instead of equal?.  When you call (= 0 (car lst)), if (car lst) is anything but a number you'll get that error, since = requires 2 numbers as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I practiced scheme but:

A) I don't think `cddr` is the correct procedure in `(+ (helper (car lst)) (count-zeroes (cddr lst)))`- it should just be cdr.

B) You don't need a second helper function- you should be able to call `(count-zeroes car lst)` just fine, because at that point you're passing a list that will be split up the same way its parent was.

So the line in contention would be `(+ (count-zeroes (car lst)) (count-zeroes (cdr lst)))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In fact, I realized that mistake (cdr instead of cddr).